# Transactional integrity across replicated node

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I'm taking a training course in DB Admin and this came to my mind during class: how can a database system ensure transactional integrity when it's replicated across multiple nodes.

For example, let say product A has 10 units left in the inventory DB. This system is replicated between America and Asia. If two clients simultaneously order 10 units of the product, before each node is aware of the other transaction, does it compromise my data integrity?

My class is in MS SQL Server but I'm also interested in how other SQL databases handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database system can't ensure transactional integrity in a distributed update-anywhere scenario.

You will have a conflict, there will be some algorithm to determine who will be the winner - possibly including manual intervention. This all depends on the implementation.

SQL Server, for example has merge replication with conflict detection and resolution. Merge replication is based on triggers that fires when you modify data to keep track of the modifications in system tables. (I wouldn't encourage anybody to use merge replication.) [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication) documentation for merge replication.

There is also transactional replication, which is based on sniffing the transaction log for changes. There's a [peer-to-peer version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-conflict-detection-in-peer-to-peer-replication) (everybody replicates to everybody) that has conflict detection only. There is also [a version with updateable subscribers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/updatable-subscriptions-queued-updating-conflict-resolution) that has conflict resolution.

Or, do what most of us do: combine HA/DR and scalability by only modify on the "master" (primary) and use the "slaves" (secondaries) for read-only queries. I.e., [Always On Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server).

Yet another option is to design the system so that each node "owns" a subset of the data and this is what that node (can) modify. This way, we will have no conflicts, assuming our applications respect this partitioning model. This is related to "sharding", but I can't say for sure if sharding means that each node *only* has a subset of the data, or if it includes all nodes having *all* the data, but is restricted to only *modify* a subset of the data.

Other DBMSs supports "[eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)", but that is a weak type of consistency. If you want to dig further you can for instance read up on the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).